# Laravel Mix remove directories

Tags: webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

In Laravel 5.4, Laravel uses laravel mix instead of elixir.
Is there a way to remove the actual copied files to public?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Laravel-Mix does not provide that. It uses `move-webpack-plugin` to copy files, which just copies files. So there is no simple solution.

To do so, I suggest that you intercept the copy parameters and delete them before mix execute them. Then move the file with your own script.

```
let copies = mix.config.copy;
mix.config.copy = undefined;

console.log(mix.config.copy);
mix.then(function () {
    copies.forEach(function(item){
        console.log('moving' + item.from  + ' to' + item.to);
        let path = require('path');
        let fs = require('fs-extra'); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra
        fs.move(path.join(mix.config.Paths.rootPath, item.from), item.to);
    });
})
```

You can also let mix copy them then you delete them.